# Changing X display manager

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, gdm

On my Ubuntu 14.04 there's `gdm` and `lightdm` installed.
Is it recommended to have both installed? How can I check which one's active and how can I change them?

I have some troubles with the Ubuntu installation as I've posted here https://askubuntu.com/questions/571245/gnome-crashing-on-ubuntu-14-04-how-can-i-fix-or-helping-fix-it and here [Ubuntu on Laptop external monitor not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566975/ubuntu-on-laptop-external-monitor-not-working-properly). I'm guessing, it could have something todo with the X display manager (but that's just a wild guess, if you have another guess, let me know).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the major display managers' packages are set to "provide" a meta-package called `x-display-manager`. When you have more than one of these, installed, running...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

...should open up a dialogue for picking the default. If that doesn't work, calling `dpkg-reconfigure` for the `gdm` (or whatever other DMs you have) should have the same effect.

Does it matter if you have more than one installed? No, but only one will be running at a time by default. You can hack something together to get both running but the defaults won't do that.

And regarding your wider problem, DMs don't actually *do* that much. The compositors and window managers (Compiz, Kwin, Mutter, etc) all contribute a lot more stress on the graphhics system.

Comment: You sir, you just made my day! I've changed the X display manager to `gdm` and are finally able to use both my monitors together! thanks! (I'd give you an upvote, but that requires 15 points ;))

Comment: @Oli, do you know what's happening behind the scenes when this command is executed?  Just wondering if this updates a config file somewhere to switch the display manager, or if it's doing something more complicated.